# Spyder Editor: Replaces portion of current line on Enter

Tags: python, editor, spyder

So I have a problem which I imagine is some setting I've messed up but can't figure where it would be.

When I use the Spyder Editor on Win 7 and Win 8.1 it replaces the last several characters of the line I'm on when press Enter to go to the next line. The text is NOT random. Sometime it is something I've recently typed into the iPython console in Spyder. Sometimes it is something I've recently typed into the Editor. Most of the time it will be something like `__class__` that I have in my code but haven't typed into the editor in days and that string isn't highlighted.

If it were only happening on 1 of my Spyder installs I would think it was something wrong with that install or a bug related to that version of Windows and the Spyder Editor but it happens in both. And it only in Spyder nothing else that this happens.

Spyder came with Anaconda (Python 2.7).

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I haven't heard of a bug like this before. The only thing I can recommend you is to try to come up with a reproducible case which we can test, debug and fix.

Comment: Would it help if I did some form of screen recording? Once it starts, it doesn't stop.

Comment: Yeah, sure, that would be fine too. Please open an issue in our issue tracker and post there the link to the video.